# Is there any way to make this code more compact?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dry

I am developing an API in python to gather information, to later on use in a learning machine. I already made a "draft" code, but is there any efficient way for this code to be as compact as it can get?

```
import requests

api_dir = 'https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/users/id?username='

tuid = input('To see stats enter an user :')

dir1 = api_dir + tuid

data_id = requests.get(dir1).json()

data_arreg = data_id['uid']

api2_dir = 'https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/users/public/br_stats_v2?user_id='

dir2 = api2_dir + data_arreg

data_stats = requests.get(dir2).json()

statskills = data_stats['overallData']['defaultModes']['kills']

statsmatch = data_stats['overallData']['defaultModes']['matchesplayed']

print('Number of total kills is {}.'.format(statskills))

print('Has a total of {} matches played.'.format(statsmatch))
```

I'm developing this code, as a way to learn API's and use the information in them. (this is why I used a fortnite API as it is similar to a personal project I want to develop later)

Comment: This is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks, didn't know about stackexchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't really repeat yourself. You can use string formatting to shorten your code by taking out variables and directly putting them in though:

```
import requests

tuid = input('To see stats enter an user :')

data_id = requests.get('https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/users/id?username={}'.format(tuid)).json()

data_stats = requests.get('https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/users/public/br_stats_v2?user_id={}'.format(data_id['uid'])).json()

print('Number of total kills is {}.\nHas a total of {} matches played.'.format(data_stats['overallData']['defaultModes']['kills'], data_stats['overallData']['defaultModes']['matchesplayed']))
```

This makes each line a little long though...